# Bootstrap Image not centering

Tags: html, css

```
   <div class="width_logo">

   <div class="left-sidebar col-md-3 thumbnail">

   <img src="../images/tech_logos.png" class="tech_logos img-responsive">

   </div>

   </div>
```

quick question, this is really getting annoying on my part. My websites contains bootstrap code. When i add my image and tried to align it to the text, it creates a gap that is not centered whenever the screen is smaller. can anyone help? I just need the image to be aligned.

[image: Fullscreen]

[image: Windowed]

Comment: did u try enclosing the image in div tag with class row and then with col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 , and if that takes care of the situation..for smaller screens you may use xs instead of md

Comment: Do you have any padding/margin in the CSS that might be causing this? If you can provide a JSfiddle with the CSS/HTML (Or more of the source codE), this would be a lot easier to check.

Comment: use the class `center-block` to your image / div.

Comment: why you use `col-md-3` to the parent div??

Comment: if you need it then use some offset here. the `center-block` must work.

Comment: hello i used col-md-3 to make the size smaller and i used margin-left in order to align the image to the text. i just want the img to be centered whenever i go windowed

Comment: share your css code of class `width_logo` , `left-sidebar` or make demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

It's an easy fix. Add the classes `img-responsive center-block` to the img. It will solve the problem. And put your text and image in same div.